# How can I correct shadow/highlight with free software?

Tags: color-correction

I have this short video and I'm trying to decrease the highlights on it since there are some overexposed areas in it.

I know some Adobe products have this shadow/highlight feature (I know it from snapseed and other image processing software) but I'm on Linux and I don't have access to software like Adobe Premiere.

Is there any open source software that I can use to apply this filter? (Preferably that's available on Linux.) So far I have tried OpenShot and DaVinci resolve, but I couldn't find that feature in any of them.

Thank you!

PS: If you have some programming-based answers (like using Python), that's also welcome.

Comment: Davinci Resolve certainly has this feature. This kind of thing is precisely what it is made for. Try this tutorial I found in two seconds when searching for 'colour grading resolve' https://blog.pond5.com/24628-basic-color-correction-and-grading-in-davinci-resolve/

Comment: @stib From what I could tell from the tutorial, it doesn't have the highlight/shadow filter that I want. It has other color correcting  features (like hue, saturation and luminance), I don't see highlight specifically. Could you point out where you see that feature, please?

Comment: @TomCho At the bottom of the color wheels, there's a 1/2 toggle.  Click the 2.  That reveals Temp, Tint, MD (similar to Adobe's "Clarity" in Lightoom), Col Boost (like "Vibrance"), Shadows, and Highlights.

Comment: Also, Clicking the disclosure triangle next to "Primaries Wheels" reveals "Log" color wheels, which are a little different than Lift, Gamma, Gain.  The high and low regions don't overlap the middle.  Plus, you could always use curves, qualifiers, or a combination of all the above.

Comment: @JasonConrad I see. I'm not familiar at all with these software so it was easy for me to miss that, but you're right, that worked. If you write an answer I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Davinci resolve, use it. If you do have it, get it and use it :o)

There are several ways to handle light and shadows, you just need to understand that lights are normally the light zones and shadows, the dark... Pretty obvious.

1. On Resolve, you can use the color panel.

[image]

2. Boost or lower the highlights on the gain wheel.
3. Or use the curves and
4. Move the curve.
5. And see the results here.

There are more advanced ways to do it, like selecting color ranges, and you can find tutorials on the internet. But the tools are there.

---

Keep in mind that on the overexposed areas, if the range is clipped, no program will recover information where there is none to recover.